# Windows does not consider monitor size in settings, only resolution

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I recently bought a 27 inch display with a resolution of 2560x1440 pixels to have a dual monitor setup. My other one is a 24 inch 1920x1080 in portrait mode.

My current issue is that the movement between the two monitor is not "linear", i.e. that the windows sort of spread out when I drag them from the main to the secondary monitor. This is also true for the mouse cursor.

I suspect the reason is that Windows doesn't know that my new monitor is 27", only that its QHD, then assumes the same pixel density (so 32" big I suppose).

I tried using the scale setting, but that only changed the size of the icons.

Is this issue only fixable by changing the resolution of the main screen to 1920x1080? Obviously, I wouldn't want to do that.

Perhaps [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m17tM.png) helps understanding my question.

My specs are the following:

- Windows 11 Pro 64-bit
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
- Monitor 1: DELL SE2723DS (DisplayPort)
- Monitor 2: DELL P2419H (HDMI)

Comment: You’re right, Windows doesn’t care about physical display size. You’ll just have to live with it.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate :(.

Comment: Strictly, it ought to *know* but as @DanielB already said, it cannot be persuaded to *care*.

Comment: As @Tetsujin states, some info on monitor size *is* available to the OS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577736/how-to-obtain-the-correct-physical-size-of-the-monitor), "you can get an approximation that depends on the DPI setting in windows, and the resolution of the screen." That said, you'd have to alter Windows OS to make any change in the presentation between screens.